# Does orientation matter when calculating inertia?

Tags: rotational-kinematics, inertia

Two cylinders having the same mass, radius, size, shape and angular property are both rotating.
[image: Does this two identical cylinders have the same inertia despite their orientation]

Does this two identical cylinders have the same inertia despite their orientation?

Comment: I assume you mean they are both rotating around the vertical axis? Then yes to the title, no to the question in the body. Moment of inertia is a tensor, meaning that (basically) it changes based on orientation. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_of_inertia

Comment: i have edited the question, can you check it now?

Comment: They appear to be rotating about the same axis however

Comment: But if the vertical line is the axis of rotation, then they have the same moment of inertia.

Comment: Yes, that is my question. they are rotating at the same axis(more importantly they are rotating around in the drawn axis), does that mean they will have the same inertia.

Comment: Are you comparing inertia values about the specified rotation axis, or 3×3 inertia tensors for any rotation possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, identical objects have the same moment of inertia about the same axis. The orientation of the object is irrelevant.

I think you are possibly concerned about the effect of gravity. This does not affect the moment of inertia of a body, which is an **intrinsic property** like mass, density and volume.

However, gravity could affect the **motion** of an asymmetric cylinder in different orientations.

For example, if the rotation axis was parallel to but did not coincide with the symmetry axis, then the distribution of mass about the rotation axis would be asymmetrical. In particular, the centre of mass would not be on the rotation axis. When the rotation axis is horizontal the gravitational force on the centre of mass exerts a torque along the axis, which varies as the cylinder rotates. The angular velocity would vary as the cylinder rotates; the cylinder could oscillate instead of rotating. When the rotation axis is vertical the torque is perpendicular to the rotation axis. It does not affect the motion of the cylinder, which rotates with constant angular velocity, and does not oscillate, in this orientation.

Comment: what is an asymmetric cylinder? and yes i was concerned about gravity.

Comment: Asymmetric means that mass is not distributed symmetrically about the axis of rotation. The cylinder is "lop-sided".

Answer (score 0):

The orientation only affects the 3×3 mass moment of inertia tensor when viewed from a common inertial frame. On their respectful body frames the inertia tensors are the same.

For example, in the world coordinate system the following tensors are defined:

[image: fig]

$$ \begin{align} 
I_1 & = \begin{bmatrix} \frac{m}{12} ( \ell^2+3 r^2) & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & \frac{m}{2} r^2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & \frac{m}{12} ( \ell^2+3 r^2) \end{bmatrix} \\
I_2 & = \begin{bmatrix} \frac{m}{2} r^2 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & \frac{m}{12} ( \ell^2+3 r^2) & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & \frac{m}{12} ( \ell^2+3 r^2) \end{bmatrix} \end{align} $$

Now since the rotation vectors are different $$\begin{align} \vec{\omega}_1 & = \pmatrix{0& \Omega & 0}^\top & \vec{\omega}_2 & = \pmatrix{\Omega &0 & 0}^\top  \end{align}$$ the angular momentum *values* are the same

$$ \| \vec{L}_1 \| = \| I_1 \vec{\omega}_1 \| = \| \pmatrix{ 0 & \frac{m}{2} \Omega r^2 & 0}^\top \| = \frac{m}{2} \Omega r^2 $$

$$ \| \vec{L}_2 \| = \| I_2 \vec{\omega}_2 \| = \| \pmatrix{ \frac{m}{2} \Omega r^2 & 0 & 0}^\top \| = \frac{m}{2} \Omega r^2 $$

Comment: in what "m x m" mass moment of inertia is it affected?

Comment: I mean the components of the 3×3 inertia tensor are different because the bodies are in different orientations. But the underlying body-frame inertia is the same ($\frac{m}{2} r^2$ along the long axis and $\frac{m}{12}( \ell^2+3 r^2)$ about the other axes).

Answer (score 0):

From the sketch, these appear to be solid cylinders,

Nothing is said about the ***distribution*** of the mass in the two cylinders.

If the mass is distributed differently in the two cylinders, then the moment of inertia will change.  The cylinder with more mass further from the central axis will have the higher moment of inertia.

There is a common physics problem to distinguish a hollow lead sphere from a solid aluminum sphere.  The thickness of the lead shell is such that the masses and radii of the two spheres are identical.  The spheres are painted, no scratching or X-raying is allowed.  The solution is to let them roll down an incline; the hollow sphere will trail behind...

Comment: Their distribution of the mass in the two cylinders is the same. They are both identical cylinders.